# Why does FullCalendar5 component not change after modifying inner calendar data?

Tags: angular, onchange, angular-components

I use FullCalendar5 component in my angular 11 application and when I reassign new events to calendar options, the changes do not affect in the view. I try following methods to solve the problem, but I do not get any result:

- Setting the "deepChangeDetection" property to "true".
- Using from calendar "reftech" render function.
- Removing all events and recreating them

Comment: It is worth mentioning, that Im using the `ChangeDetectorRef`  of `@angular/core` and by calling `detectchanges` function everything works fine. but why does `deepChangeDetection` not working?